# If i randomly select $n+1$ integers smaller that $2n$ , must there include an integer which divisible with one of the others?

Tags: combinatorics

If i randomly  select $n+1$ integers smaller that $2n$ , must there include an integer which divisible with one of the others?

I think it seems possible but not sure how to prove it. What i know is that there contains $n$ even and odd numbers.

Comment: yes, it comes from the pigeonhole principle, think about 2.

Comment: I suppose negative integers are not permitted?

Comment: The randomness is an unnecessary distraction; the question could more generally ask about arbitrary integers.

Comment: @Sarastro of course.

Comment: This has appeared on MSE several times before. Take the odd numbers $2k-1$, $k=1$ to $n$. Into pigeonhole $k$, put all numbers that are of the form $2^e (2k-1)$.